# Javascript - array of img-strings append number to specific attribute

Tags: javascript

I have an array of `<img .../>`-strings and I want to append a number into the `foo` attribute of selected ones. I have made up this code as an example, where `my_imgs` is the array of `<img .../>`-strings:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Append integer into the 'foo'-attribute of an 'img'-tag - Test</title>
    <script>        
        function my_function(some_img, some_integer){
            //magic happens :-(
            return some_img_with_appended_integer;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>        
        var my_imgs = ["<img src='1.png' foo='99 1 33' bar='qwertz1' harhar='yxcvb1' />",
                       "<img src='2.png' foo='2 3' bar='qwertz2' harhar='yxcvb2' someother='x' />",
                       "<img src='3.png' foo='9 7 2' bar='qwertz3' harhar='yxcvb3' />"];
        console.log("my_imgs = " + my_imgs);    
        my_function(my_imgs[0],"987"); // --> must return: "<img src='1.png' foo='99 1 33 987' bar='qwertz1' harhar='yxcvb1' />"
        my_function(my_imgs[1],"76"); // --> must return: "<img src='2.png' foo='2 3 76' bar='qwertz2' harhar='yxcvb2' someother='x' />"
        my_function(my_imgs[2],"345"); // --> must return: "<img src='3.png' foo='9 7 2 345' bar='qwertz3' harhar='yxcvb3' />"
    </script>
</body>
```

I basically know [these tools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp) are neccessary to solve this, but i am struggling to solve my problem and therefore wanted to ask for some help.

Comment: Do you _have_ to deal with them as strings?  This would be far easier if you were dealing with actual `<img>` elements...

Comment: If it is possible to convert the `<img>`-elements somehow to a string representation after appending the number, then it would be ok. (I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can achieve this using `createElement` which will create new `DOM element`. `append` the `image` element in created element using `innerHTML` and then you can find that element using `getElementsByTagName` and using `DOM node` methods like `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` to manipulate `attributes`.

Try this:

```js
function my_function(some_img, some_integer) {
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = some_img;
  var image = elem.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  var attribute = image.getAttribute('foo');
  image.setAttribute('foo', attribute + ' ' + some_integer);
  return image.outerHTML;
}
var my_imgs = ["<img src='1.png' foo='99 1 33' bar='qwertz1' harhar='yxcvb1' />",
  "<img src='2.png' foo='2 3' bar='qwertz2' harhar='yxcvb2' someother='x' />",
  "<img src='3.png' foo='9 7 2' bar='qwertz3' harhar='yxcvb3' />"
];

var modified = my_function(my_imgs[0], "987");
alert(modified);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string `replace()` with a regex:

```
function my_function(str, number) {
    return str.replace( /foo='(.*?)'/, "foo='$1 " + number + "'")
}
```

Note that this relies on using `'` for quoting the attribute value - if you're going to have a mixture of `'` and `"` you'll need a slightly more sophisticated regex, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `HTML DOM Element` of the img tag and the set it's new attribute.

```
function my_function(some_img, some_integer){
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = some_img;
            var el = div.childNodes[0];
            var foo = el.getAttribute("foo")+" "+some_integer;
            el.setAttribute("foo", foo);
            return el;
        }
```